# On unitary transformation for two Irreducible representations of space group 198

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, physics, solid-geometry

I am considering the irreducible representation (IR) of space group 198, which consists of two generators

$$
\left\{C_3\right\}: (x,y,z)\rightarrow(z,x,y)\\
\left\{C_{2x}\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right\}: (x,y,z)\rightarrow(x+\frac{1}{2},-y+\frac{1}{2},-z)
$$
There is an additional generator $\left\{C_{2y}\big|0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ which satisfies $C_3C_{2x}C_3^{-1}=C_{2y}$, which we will not explicitly consider because given the reps of $C_3,C_{2x}$, we have the rep for $C_{2y}$ automatically.

Now I have two sets of IR $\rho^{1,2}$ which are of the following

$$
\rho^{1}(C_3) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
\rho^{1}(\left\{C_{2x}\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right\}) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and

$$
\rho^{2}(C_3) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
\rho^{2}(\left\{C_{2x}\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right\}) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Question: How to find the unitary matrix $U$ such that $U\rho^{1}(g)U^{-1}=\rho^{2}(g)$ for both $g=C_{3},C_{2x}$?

Such unitary transformation should exist, because the 6-fold IR for SG 198 should be unique. Note also that the characters of the IRs are the same, so I think they should be isomorphic?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Aren't $\rho^1(C_3)$ and $\rho^2(C_3)$ order six, whereas $C_3$ is order three? How is that possible? Are these projective representations rather than linear representations?

Comment: Also, it might help to find the invariant subspaces of each matrix element.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just an extended comment which does not fit in the footnote format for them.

Your 6×6 matrices are manifestly transcribable into tensor products of 2×2 identity matrices *I* , or Pauli rotations $I/2+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_2= \exp (i(\pi/3) \sigma_2 )$, tensored to 3×3 matrices,
$$
S\equiv  \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 1   \\
  1 & 0 & 0   \\
  0 & 1 & 0   \\ 
\end{array}
\right), ~~~ S^3=1\!\! 1, \\
T\equiv  \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  -1 & 0 & 0   \\
  0& 1 & 0   \\
  0 & 0 & 1   \\ 
\end{array}
\right)= S  \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & 0   \\
  0& 1 & 0   \\
  0 & 0 & -1   \\ 
\end{array}
\right)      S^2, 
$$
that is
$$
\rho^{1}(C_3) =  \exp (i(\pi/3) \sigma_2 ) \otimes S^2,  \\
\rho^{1}(\left\{C_{2x}\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right\}) =I\otimes  
 S^2T S      ,\\
\rho^{2}(C_3) = -I\otimes S , \\
\rho^{2}(\left\{C_{2x}\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right\}) = I\otimes  
 T~.
$$

However, all one can see is that *U* for  $U\rho^{1}(g)U^{-1}=\rho^{2}(g)$ is not
a simple tensor product $u\otimes {\mathfrak U}$ of  2×2  and  3×3 matrices, as the respective block traces mismatch in places, e.g. the  2×2  of $C^3$.

While not an answer, the comment might help you with ideas...